# Unable to open any terminal

Tags: 14.04

Unable to open any Terminal like xterm, Terminator in GUI. In <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd> terminal unable to login with correct password i.e it doesn't says that incorrect login but just refresh and asks for login again.

Comment: Sounds like there's something in you shell initialization sequence (e.g. `~/.bashrc` file) that's causing the shell to exit as soon as it starts

Comment: So what did you change?  Use a live session to examine and correct any mistakes.

Comment: What is, when you try it via way with keys 'Alt' + 'F2' ? - then type into query "Terminal" or "terminal" ?!

Comment: I have hadoop insatlled and recently i have installed sftp maybe sftp causing the problem. Help please!

Comment: @dschinn1001 there is no response.  Maybe it's bashrc but how to edit that file without terminal commands?

Comment: If you are able to open `nautilus` (the file browser) in the GUI, you should be able to open it in a text editor, or rename it e.g. `~/.bashrc.old` or whatever. Or simply copy a "clean" version from the `/etc/skel` directory. You will need to "Show hidden files" either from the nautilus menu or by hitting Ctrl-H

Comment: I copied the clean .bashrc file from /etc/skel to .bashrc of home but no difference still unable to access the terminal but i discovered that i can access the terminal from Guest Account

Comment: @NiteshGupta - This was a bug in earlier version of Ubuntu too. You could re-install with live-CD (live-USB-stick), but only overwrite the / Directory (only root-Directory) without to change the /home - Directory.

Answer (score 0):

This is not secure as hint, but this could help, but only when gnome is your
windows-manager :

> sudo apt-get install --reinstall bash gnome-terminal

In case of windows-manager xfce4 you type :

> sudo apt-get install --reinstall bash xfce4-terminal

In case of unity a rebound of packages could help as follows :

> sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3-all
>
> sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-terminal
>
> sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
>
> sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity

Then in the end :

> sudo reboot

This hint could help too :

You should clean you ubuntu installation with software-package bleachbit, perhaps some caches are untidy. And keep it clean too with clamav.

Comment: Where to write all this command. I'm unable to access the terminal. Anyway thanks for your efforts but still stuck.